# How can I Highlight the google map polygon borders on click?

Tags: angular, typescript, maps

I am using Google Map API JS in angular, and I am showing the multiple polygons on map and I want to highlight the border of the polygon when I clicks on polygon, but its highlighting the only last polygon only. In below I am sharing the Stackblitz URL for reference

Demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-1pdan5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please help me in these issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change your listener code to

```
this.polygonsMap.addListener('click', function() {
      this.setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#000'
      });
    });
```

so that when you click on any polygon its stroke color woill be changed

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the click event to the whole map and use local variable

```
  drawPolygon() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: { lat: 64.79728743642762, lng: -150.995535452303 },
      zoom: 7
    });
    // create empty array
    // we will fill in all the polygons created in this array
    let polygonArray = [];

    this.polygons.filter((data: any) => {
      data.data.filter((res: any) => {
        // create new polygon
        let polygonsMap = new google.maps.Polygon({
          map: this.map,
          paths: res.polygons,
          strokeColor: '#FF8C00',
          fillColor: '#FF8C00',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });
        polygonsMap.setMap(this.map);

        // add event listener
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygonsMap, 'click', function(event) {
          //all polygons are reset before painting the clicked polygon
          for (let i in polygonArray) {
            polygonArray[i].setOptions({ fillColor: '#FF8C00' });
            polygonArray[i].setOptions({ strokeColor: '#FF8C00' });
          }

          // clicked polygon paint
          polygonsMap.setOptions({ fillColor: '#000' });
          polygonsMap.setOptions({ strokeColor: '#000' });
        });

        // push to polygonArray
        polygonArray.push(polygonsMap);
      });
    });

    // Show polyogon array
    console.log('polygonArray', polygonArray);
  }
```

Working Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-du2yeq?file=app/app.component.ts

Documentation : [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#MVCObject.addListener)

Comment: Thanks all for answers. But is there any possibilities if i click on (1)one polygon after color will change and again i will click (2) another polygon now the two polygons were filled with same color and i need to remove the fill color of  previous polygon i;e (1) when i clicked (2) polygon

Comment: you can push all polygons into an array and reset them all from there. `polygonArray.push(polygonsMap); for(let i in polygonArray) { polygonArray[i].setOptions({fillColor : '#FF8C00'}) } `. edit answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the features have an id on them:

```
    map.data.addListener('click', (event) => {
      const clickedId = event.feature.getId()

      map.data.setStyle((feature) => {
        const featureId = feature.getId()
        if (clickedId == featureId) {
          return {
            fillColor: '#800080',
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeColor: '#00FFFF', //highlight stroke
            strokeWeight: 3, //increased stroke weight
          }
        } else {
          return {
            fillColor: '#800080',
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
          }
        }
      }) 
})
```